# How do I save user-selected parameters in a drop-down list when POST is triggered?

Tags: python, flask

There are drop-down lists with multiselection, when user selected required parameters and pressed "apply" button, table appears with parameters selected by user, but selected parameters themselves are not saved in drop-down list, i.e. all ticks set by user are lost.

Can you please advise how to make the user's selection saved when the POST method is triggered?

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    with psycopg2.connect(**params) as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM fact_est_bp;") 
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        selected_years = [int(i) for i in request.form.getlist("year") if i.isdigit()]
        print(selected_years)
        selected_stations = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("station")]
        print(selected_stations)
        indicators = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("indicators")]
        print(indicators)
        columns = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("columns")]
        print(columns)
        with psycopg2.connect(**params) as conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT {} FROM fact_est_bp WHERE year = ANY(%s) AND indicators = ANY(%s) AND station_name = ANY(%s);"
                        .format(",".join(["\"{}\"".format(c) for c in columns])),(selected_years, indicators, selected_stations))
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()
        filename = "fact_T2.xlsx"
        filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
        workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
        worksheet = workbook.active
        worksheet.append(columns)
        for row in rows:
            worksheet.append(list(row))           
        workbook.save(filepath)
        return render_template("index.html", rows=rows, columns=columns, selected_years=selected_years, now=datetime.utcnow(), selected_stations=selected_stations, 
form_visible=True)
    else:
        return render_template("index.html", rows=rows, form_visible=False)
```

I was able to do it for numbers (years), but how do I do it for text?

```
  <form method ="post" action="/">
    <label for="year"></label>
    <select type="number" id = "year" name ="year" class="selectpicker" data-actions-box="true" multiple="multiple">
      <option class="optionGroup" selected disabled>Выберите год(а)</option>
      {% for year in range(2014, now.year+1) %}
      <option value="{{ year }}"{% if year in selected_years %} selected{% endif %}>{{ year }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select><br><br>
```

text, for example

```
<label for="station"></label>
    <select type="text" id="station" name="station" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" multiple="multiple">
      <option class="optionGroup" selected disabled>Select stations</option>
      <optgroup label="Chk">
        <option value="chk">chk</option>
        <option value="chtetz-1">chtetz-1</option>
        <option value="gtu">gtu</option>
        <option value="read-1 PT">read-1 PT</option>
        <option value="read-2">read-2</option>
        <option value="read-3">read-3</option>
        <option value="chtetz-4">tetz-4</option>
        <option value="read-4 igu-1">read-4 igu-1</option>
        <option value="read-4 igu-2">read-4 igu-2</option>
        <option value="read-4 igu-3">read-4 igu-3</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Tyumen">
</select><br><br>
```